# CodeName One demo CleanModern

Tags: codenameone

demo CleanModem singUpForm not working!!
the problem is at the level:
Container content = BoxLayout.encloseY(
                new Label("Sign Up", "LogoLabel"),
                new FloatingHint(username),
                createLineSeparator(),
                new FloatingHint(email),
                createLineSeparator(),
                new FloatingHint(password),
                createLineSeparator(),
                new FloatingHint(confirmPassword),
                createLineSeparator()
        );

Comment: When asking these things you should explain where you got the demo from (there are two ways), simulator or device and which one. The exception you got and its stack trace etc. Since all of those are missing some community members downvoted your question

Comment: Retesting the code I see there is a regression with some edge cases of floating hint. I assume it doesn't happen with the new `TextComponent` which replaces that. I'm looking into this and will post an answer when I have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a regression in Codename One which was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/b0438d33953176686af1e9cb4bd88f08963bd4df). It will be in the build servers next Friday (December 1st 2017) but you can already [use the sources](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/how-to-use-the-codename-one-sources.html) to see that it works.

I'm still not sure why this was triggered, we made several changes to focus behavior that seemed to have impacted that but I can't seem to find one specific problematic change so I'm guessing it's due to more than one change. The `FloatingHint` class used by that demo was deprecated recently and replaced with a newer `TextComponent` class which shouldn't suffer from these issues. I've filed an [RFE to update the usage of FloatingHint](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2284).

However, `FloatingHint` should still work so I patched it to workaround this problem which is caused due to the usage of blocking animation. Normally that isn't a problem but for some reason this is now triggered before the new form is showing and it's unclear how that can happen. The patch prevents the animation from occurring unless the parent `Form` is **really** showing.